# ArcObjects: How to get the Cell Size from the raster.MeanCellSize call?

Tags: arcobjects

When I setup the call to MeanCellSize -- for which ESRI documentation states will return the mean average of the cell size -- all I get is an IPnt object.  I've played with a ton of the various casts but cannot figure out what to cast it to so that I can actually get a value for the mean cell size!!  Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: Can you not simply ask the X property of the ipnt object? I thought esri only supported square cells for rasters?

Comment: @Hornbydd, wouldn't the X property just be the X-coordinate of the ipnt? I am also curious as to how an ipnt can represent a cell size value (as it doesn't seem to have this property attached to it). This might be a good question to raise on the ESRI forums if you can't find a solution here.

Comment: IRasterProps.MeanCellSize returns an IPnt object but IRasterProps is pointing to a raster, so at no point (no pun intended) are you referencing a single cell in a raster. I'm guessing that ESRI are returning an IPnt object where X and Y are the width and height of a cell rather than a coordinate?

Comment: The arcobjects documentation claims X and Y properties are coordinates of the ipnt. Misleading perhaps (if they do happen to represent cell dimensions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this VBA to check what the IPnt properties X and Y are and they are indeed the cell size and not a coordinate.

```
Public Sub cellsize()
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXD.FocusMap
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
    Dim pRasterlayer As IRasterLayer
    Set pRasterlayer = pLayer
    Dim pRaster As IRaster
    Set pRaster = pRasterlayer.Raster
    Dim pRasterProps As IRasterProps
    Set pRasterProps = pRaster
    Dim pPnt As IPnt
    Set pPnt = pRasterProps.MeanCellSize
    Debug.Print pPnt.X
    Debug.Print pPnt.Y
End Sub
```